# Getting original value back after percentage increase?

Tags: javascript, python, php, math

I am a store owner.

The bank deducts 10%

How can I set my prices to be 10% extra.

e.g

Product costs $34

Add 10% and send $37.40 to the bank, then bank deducts 10% of $37.40, leaving the store with only $33.70, while 10% deduction should leave the store with $34

How much additional to add to the $34 so that the deduction leaves $34.

The best I can do is

34 + 10% = result

result + 1% = value to send to bank

value send to bank - 10% and roundup = 34

Needing commonly used formula.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 34 * 10/9 = 37.777..

Comment: multiply by 1.1 recurring, noted

Answer (score 1):

Take the current price and divide it by (100 - bank percent) then multiple all by 100.

so you have $34.00 and you say this is reduced by 10%, but you want the final dollar value you get to be $34.00.  So what is the starting price if you know the bank takes 10%.

```
origPrice = (34.00/(100-10)) * 100 = 37.78
```

So if you set the price at $37.78 and the bank takes 10%, you should have $34.00 deposited to the good.
Another good example on how to think of it, is this youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUxPEApSJ7U&t=1s

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`bank price = intial price * 1.12`

Example
`37.74 = 34 * 1.12`

I suggest adding 12% to the price